# How to retrieve the value of a pointer column from parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to retrieve the value stored in a pointer type column in parse. I am using the following:

```
ParseQuery test = ParseUser.getQuery();
                test.include("_Installation"); 
                test.getInBackground("EMqw4TOQ0c", new GetCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                        id = parseObject.get("identification").toString();
                        Log.d("SUCCESS !!! :",id);
                    }
                });
```

With this I get `com.parse.ParseInstallation@42619a80` the value of the `id` which is wrong.

How can I get the correct value stored?

Comment: Do you mean that "com.parse.ParseInstallation@42619a80" is not the installation identifier for user with id "EMqw4TOQ0c"?  It sure looks like it is.

Comment: @danh The idea is to get the id of the Installation class, the id provided in the code is from the User class, and `identification` is the name of the column holding the pointer value pointing to the Installation class.

Comment: @danh This is i think what I am looking for but it is in javascript [Multidimensional Includes](https://coderwall.com/p/cy6cea/how-to-use-pointers-relations-parse-com-javascript-sdk)  , and I cannot find a way to incorporate it to android

Comment: @olympus how u incorporate it in android ?